# Why GCC 8.2 compilation throwing errors during soft floating point sources?

Tags: c++

When I am compiling gcc 8.2 on RHEL 6 (x86-64 arch) I am running into below issue

../../../libgcc/soft-fp/fixtfti.c:33:1: error: unknown type name 'TItype'; did you mean 'TFtype'?
 TItype
 ^~~~~~
 TFtype
../../../libgcc/soft-fp/fixtfti.c: In function '__fixtfti':

../../../libgcc/soft-fp/fixtfti.c:38:3: error: unknown type name 'UTItype'; did you mean 'UDItype'?
   UTItype r;
   ^~~~~~~
   UDItype

I compiled dependent gmp/mpfr/mpc/binutils/isl successfully and using them in my GCC compilation.

GCC configure command used:

../configure --prefix=/home/zk46w9e/apps/gcc-8.2.0-compliant/compiler/gcc-8.2/ --enable-gold --enable-libssp  --enable-vtable-verify --enable-host-shared --enable-lto --with-mpc=/home/zk46w9e/apps/gcc-8.2.0-compliant/mpc/mpc-1.1.0  --with-mpfr=/home/zk46w9e/apps/gcc-8.2.0-compliant/mpfr/mpfr-4.0.1  --with-gmp=/home/zk46w9e/apps/gcc-8.2.0-compliant/gmp/gmp-6.1.2 --with-isl=/home/zk46w9e/apps/gcc-8.2.0-compliant/isl/isl-0.19 --enable-languages=c++ --disable-multilib --disable-nls  --enable-threads=posix --enable-tls  --enable-__cxa_atexit --enable-plugins

Still running into above issue. Can somebody throw some light?

Comment: Can you try with just `./configure --prefix=path/to/install` and let us know what happens?

Comment: configure: error: Building GCC requires GMP 4.2+, MPFR 2.4.0+ and MPC 0.8.0+.
Try the --with-gmp, --with-mpfr and/or --with-mpc options to specify
their locations.  I am getting this error if i try without any options

Comment: Great, now specify those options and try compiling again. Let us know what happens. I found [this](http://gcc.1065356.n8.nabble.com/unknown-type-name-TItype-td639566.html) online which suggests unsetting `CFLAGS` and `CFLAGS_FOR_TARGET` but this was for i386 architecture.

Comment: Still same issue occurring. I tried unsetting CFLAGS etc before posting issue in stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to compile GCC 32 bit , 64 bit individually by passing flags like -m32 etc which caused above error.

After passing --with-multilib-list=m32,m64 as option for GCC configure and reran the compilation, compilation went fine without any issues

thank you newkid for help